# Does one capitalize "communism" and "communist"?

Tags: orthography, capitalization, proper-nouns

Suppose I have the following sentence:

> I lived in a communist country during the fall of communism in 1989.

Should "communist" and "communism" be capitalized?

Comment: Could have elaborated on what makes you think so.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The correct capitalization for that sentence is:

> I lived in a **communist** country during the Fall of **Communism** in 1989.

(You may want to keep "fall" in lower case.)

A proper noun should be capitalized, as it is a unique entity. A common noun represents a class of entities or non-unique instances of that class, according to the English SE tag for proper nouns. Applying that definition, "a communist country" is an example of a common noun. It should not be capitalized.

The other occurrence of communism in the sentence is a specific instance. (I presume that it refers to the former Soviet Union? Or another nation, doesn't really matter which one). It is unique by virtue of the fact that it was "of 1989". That is why the second occurrence of communism in your sentence *should* be capitalized.

Comment: Minor point: I disagree with the capital F.  People who live through events perceive the fall of a government or the battle in their town: it is only historians who talk about the Fall of Communism or the Battle of Moscow.

Comment: @TimLymington: On the other hand, I think the reference is to the event, the *Fall of Communism* as it is to the event, the *Battle of Moscow* and not to Communism or Moscow as such. So, the capitalization may be understandable.

Comment: @Kris Yes! Regarding capitalization, that is what I had in mind, given the context (referring to the year 1989).

Comment: I don't see very many references with a capital F in "the fall of the Roman Empire" or "the fall of the Berlin Wall", even though they are about on the same level.

Answer (score 14):

*Communism* is a common noun and, as such, neither it, nor any adjective derived from it, normally needs to begin with a capital letter. If, however, the adjective is part of a title, as in *The Communist Party of Trashkanistan* or *The People's Communist Republic of Transculpania*, or if the noun appears in a slogan such as *Workers of the World Fight for the Victory of Communism*, then the initial capital would be in order.

Comment: This is probably my favorite content across all of StackExchange. Every time I decide whether to capitalize “communist”, it gives me the opportunity to revisit it. Thank you, @BarrieEngland. #Trashkanistan

Comment: @Lucas I saw this now for the first time. I agree! #Trashkanistan is quite excellent! I might suggest a slight alteration, to #Trashkhanistan but am uncertain as the 'hkh' might be a distraction rather than an improvement. Thank you, Barrie.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, *communist* is a description so has no capital letter, just as the USA is a democratic country (and has a republican form of government) whether the current government is Democratic or Republican.

*Communism* is more complex, and I think it depends slightly on your politics.  Small-c communism is a political idea, named (probably) from the Paris Commune of 1870, but going back at least as far as the early Christian Church.  Lenin, in 1917, set up a state on avowedly communist (as opposed to democratic or monarchical) principles.  This became a multi-national, totalitarian system going by the name of Communism (or, internally, Socialism as in US *S* R) but certainly not communist.  If you think the 1990 fall of that system discredited the idea, it should be a small c; if it had no more to do with communism than the German Democratic Republic had to do with democracy, use a capital.